# HTML5 - Password Regex

Tags: regex, html, passwords

I try to make a valid html5 pattern for a Password. It should be at least 9 characters long and contain at least one Uppercase, one lowercase, one digit and one specialcharacter of this list

()[]{}?!$%&/=*+~,.;:<>-_

I made this regex but it doesn't work... anyone can fix this?

`pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[()[]{}?!$%&/=*+~,.;:<>-_])(?=.*[A-Z]).{9,}?$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[()\[\]{}?!$%&/=*+~,.;:<>_-])(?=.*[A-Z]).{9,}"
```

There are several errors:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[()[]{}?!$%&/=*+~,.;:<>-_])(?=.*[A-Z]).{9,}?$
# ] needs to be escaped ----^^                  ^                   ^
# otherwise it will close the character class   |                   |
# [ too but for no logical reason               |                   |
# the - is used to define a character range ----+                   |
# the range >-_ gives >?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_            |
# there's no reason to make this quantifier non-greedy -------------+
```

In addition, anchors `^` and `$` are implicit, you don't have to put them.

Note that using ranges, you can also write the pattern like that:

```
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!$%&(-/:-?_{}~])(?=.*[A-Z]).{9,}"
```